# Storing small data in a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, struct, void

To keep this simple, I have a struct along the lines of

```
typedef struct foo 
{
 void *data;
 size_t sz;
 /* various other crap */
} foo_t;
```

but I'm finding about 90% of the time it really just needs to store a byte or at most a short (but, sometimes, it needs to be a big section of memory). Am I asking for a headache to wrap gets and sets with functions that do some sort of size checking and just store and read the small data directly in data rather than using it as a pointer? The logic seems pretty simple, e.g.

```
if (f->sz <= sizeof(void*) && f->sz == sizeof(char)) 
{
 return (char) f->data; 
}
```

The advisability of this from a maintenance perspective aside (on the one hand, it makes freeing 90% of the structs much easier and doesn't allocate tons of single chars God knows where on the heap; on the other hand, it means every read and write now has multiple code paths it might take, meaning I'll hate this at some point in the future), is there any particular reason I *can't* just store a char (or anything else not larger than sizeof(void*)) in a pointer and read it back later? Am I going to hit endian problems or whatever on weird platforms? I remember way back a CS prof saying "it's wrong to say 'pointers are integers'; integers are one way of implementing pointers" but I don't know if he was just making a conceptual point, or if there are real problems with storing non-address data in a spot the compiler has been told is a pointer.

(I mean, obviously if I then mistakenly *use* one of those as a pointer, that's going to cause pain, but I'm too smart to ever do that... right?...)

Comment: `union { void *ptr; char byte; short sh; } data;`

Comment: Fair enough. But then at write-time I don't know how big a pointer is going to be at compile-time (but this solves 90% of my 90% of the issue... I'll give it a try).

Comment: @userXXX huh... what?

Comment: @user3075658, why wouldn't you know? That would still be just `sizeof(data)`

Comment: The answer is "you will have to decide for yourself". I can address one point though: "Am I going to hit endian problems" No, you're not. It doesn't matter how the pointers are stored, as long as you do the proper casting when storing and retrieving, it doesn't matter what it looks like.

Comment: A pointer could be 4 or 8 bytes (or God knows what). I don't want to make my structs any bigger (and a union is always as big as its largest possible element). I want to use the space from the pointer to store a number if that number can be stored in the space of a pointer or less. But sitting here programming, I don't know the pointer size of the platform this will be compiled on (but the compiler will).

Comment: Mr. Lister, thank you. I still think this will probably be a bad idea, but that was what I wanted to know...

Comment: @user3075658 Then you can cast from/to `(u)intptr_t`. Conversion between pointers and integers is implementation-defined, an in practice, it almost always "just works".

Comment: @Jens but I can't make the union elements depend on sizeof(anything); I don't want to include something larger than sizeof(void *), and I want to get everything the size of sizeof(void *) or smaller.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to access it transparently as a data pointer use

```
union overlay {
  void* point;
  unsigned char array[sizeof(void*)];
};
```

and have some code like

```
inline
void* get_data_pointer(struct foo* f) {
  return (f->sz > sizeof(void*)) ? f->data.point : f->data.array;
};
```

*Edit*: There is no deal with data layout for your small types with such an approach. Your other code sees a `void*` in any case and stores data to the corresponding object as it pleases (and retrieves it the same way afterwards). As nos pointed out, the only possible issue could be with alignment requirements for the data that you want to store. Generally data types that are smaller than `void*` would have less restrictive alignment requirements than `void*`. I don't know of any platform where that could be a problem.

BTW, type names with ending `_t` are reserved by POSIX, you shouldn't define them in your code. There would be nothing wrong by using the same name for the type identifier as for the `struct` tag.

```
typedef struct foo foo;
```

Comment: I like that, though it changes the struct. I'll give that a try too; though it means I have to handle my own endian-ness there. Thanks.

Comment: @user3075658 Why is endianess any issue here ? Are you going to store this struct externally somehow ?

Comment: @nos I learned C in the 80s (and haven't thought about it much since) when endianness was a headache everybody had, and old habits die hard. I'd like my program to not depend on the platform it's being executed on; I could imagine a platform where pointers were stored with an endianness different from an int of the equivalent size, but apparently with casts the compiler takes care of that for me...

Comment: @user3075658 There's anyway no issue with that here. You store whatever you need in the unsigned char array and retreive it from that array, or you store a pointer in the void*. If there would be any issue here, it's if the alignment requirement of whatever you store in the array is greater than that of a void*. Assuming you'd want to store a char, short, int or float there, I havn't seen such a platform though.

Comment: The structs are on the heap anyways; if I'm going to add a 4-char array to all of them I might as well just malloc() the single byte and point data to it (since it will end up hogging a whole word of memory most of the time). I'd rather have fewer malloc() and free() calls if possible...

Comment: @user3075658 What are you talking about now ? You orignally had a void*, which now is made into a union which will have the same size as that void*. There's no extra anything here. Btw the `unsigned char* array[sizeof(void*)]` should be `unsigned char array[sizeof(void*)]` (i.e. not an array of pointers)

Comment: @nos to your "no issue" point, if I'm feeding bytes into a 4-char array to build an int (or whatever), then the endianness is whatever I say it is. If I give a small enough number to the compiler and tell it to store it at the starting address of the 4-char array, the compiler will do whatever it does and, with an appropriate cast, read back to me what it stored at some point in the future. But if I'm already casting stuff, it makes more sense to me to just put the data directly in the pointer...

Answer (score 0):

What you should use is a `union`, for example:

```
union foo {
  void *data;
  size_t sz;
  /* various other crap */
}
```

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm) on using unions in C.

Comment: I know what a union is, Phonon; I also know that before compile-time I don't know how big a pointer is on any hypothetical platform this is being compiled on, so this may only solve part of my problem.

Comment: @H2CO3, sure it matters, `size_t` could be too big, and blow up the structure. But I admit that this is unlikely.

Comment: @JensGustedt In what sense could it "blow up" anything? A `union` allocates at least as much space as the size of its biggest member. There can't be any problems (on a conforming implementation, anyway).

Comment: @H2CO3 exactly, and I don't want to make my structs bigger. I want to keep the struct I have and abuse the fact that the pointer is implemented as an integer of some specific size, but *before it's compiled* I can't know how big of a number that pointer can actually hold. I mean, I could just say "if it's a char store it there" (since any type has to be at least a char big) and be done with it...

Comment: @user3075658 Yes, you can just cast to/from any integral type T for which `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void *)`.

Comment: @piokuc, I must have explained it backwards: that union would take all of my struct fields and only make one of them available, which definitely isn't what a want.

Here's a nice tutorial on using unions in C...

Comment: @JensGustedt, also, I don't want a uintptr_t because I'm storing a data size, not a memory address. I (in some cases) need to be able to index the data as an array (which size_t guarantees), but I don't need a full uintptr_t (in cases where they are different).

Answer (score 0):

size_t is unsigned int. Declare implicitly and the size of pointer void also is equal to the size of int on specific compiler. There is a concept called packing and in gcc by default it is 4. e.g
       struct s
       {
       char c; 
       int a;
       }
so the size of s is 8 bytes not 5 bytes because the three bytes will not use this concept is related to operating system concept.
            if (f->sz <= sizeof(void*) && f->sz == sizeof(char)) 
              {
              return (char) f->data; 
              }
here what you try to do. f->sz will return the value what ever you stored in sz variable and sizeof(void*) will return 4. Now return (char) f->data this will return the address and how cast an address to char it is always an integer. Here you are only returning the least significant byte. Suppose f->data=0xaabbccdd; So the data stored at last least significant byte is 0xdd and hence by typecasting with char you are return only this value.
If you have confusion then print printf("%p",f->data) and after returning its where will you receive this value again print that value. Here %p will print the value in hex format. May be here I confuse just check to net how to print in hex format. I think this may be helpful for you
thanks 
asif aftab

Comment: If you have any problem related with little and big endian then please ask I will give you answer.